# How to use EmguCV on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: python, ubuntu-18.04, emgucv, python.net

I am trying to use EmguCV with Python, but failed.
Here are the things I have done and tried:

```
Python version: 3.6.9
pip version: 20.1.1
```

I have installed the requirements of pythonnet:

```
pytest==3.2.5
coverage
psutil
pycparser
mono
```

Then installed pythonnet(command: `pip install pythonnet`) and EmguCV (follow the instructions of [Download_And_Installation](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Download_And_Installation))

and here is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import clr
#-----------import EmguCV--------------
clr.AddReference("Emgu.CV")
#clr.AddReferenceToFile("Emgu.CV.dll") #is it not supported in pythonnet?
from Emgu.CV import *
```

I tried to import EmguCV but failed, here is the message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "try.py", line 15, in <module>
    clr.AddReference("Emgu.Util")
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Unable to find assembly 'Emgu.Util'.
  at Python.Runtime.CLRModule.AddReference (System.String name) [0x00057] in <ad8146de257247f091af8d3b9a402023>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x0006a] in <f2b3ab7dfff746f594d2ef5b16ec3c90>:0
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: So, do you have `Emgu.Util` in the same folder as `Emgu.CV`?

Comment: @LOST Yes, I do have Emgu.Util.dll in the same folder.